# Convert the dd-mm-yyyy format into yyyy-mm-dd format in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have to use isdate() function of SQL. It will return 1 if this function found a valid date(yyyy-mm-dd). I have a date column but in dd-mm-yyyy format. So this function is not able to work.

In SSMS(SQL Server management studio) i write query

```
declare @getdata varchar(max)
set @getdata=  '[
        {
            "name": "21-01-1998",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "29-01-1998",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "299-01-1998",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "folder1",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "output",
            "type": "Folder"
        }
    ]'
```

then i used openjson function to convert the json format into tabular structure

```
select * from openjson(@getdata) with (foldername varchar(10) '$.name')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cvp8.png)

I am writing this query and i am not getting result because my date is in dd-mm-yyy format.

```
select * from openjson(@getdata) with (foldername varchar(10) '$.name') where isdate(foldername) =1
```

Comment: Why must you use `IsDate` rather than [`Try_Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? Using `style` `105` would help. Aside: You don't have a "date column" if the data type is _prose that might refer to a date_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set dateformat

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

select ISDATE(foldername), * from openjson(@getdata) with (foldername varchar(10) '$.name') 
    where isdate(foldername) =1
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CONVERT() function to convert the date string to the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format before applying the ISDATE() function.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@getdata)
WITH (foldername VARCHAR(10) '$.name') 
WHERE ISDATE(CONVERT(DATE, foldername, 105)) = 1;
```

Comment: `CONVERT(DATE, foldername, 105)` will create a value with data type date or throw an error for inputs like `'299-01-1998'`. So the `ISDATE` check won't do anything as you are definitely already passing it a date or the query as a whole has errored

Comment: In fact `ISDATE` doesn't even accept arguments of datatype `DATE` - understandably